# Javascript validation seems not working? is there any error?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to search the error for 3 hours but i dont know why it doesn't work. Can anyone help me pls? :( When i started to press the sumbit button, the whole form refresh. It is like returning true instead of returning false. I did link my javascript to my html. I put the linking at the bottom before ending the body tag.

```
    <script src="../Js/feedbackscript.js"></script>
```

My html:

```
 <div id="form-main">
 <div id="form-div">

<form method="POST" class="form" id="form1" name="Form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

  <p class="name">
    <input name="name" type="text"   class="feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
                    <div id="name_error" class="val_error"></div>
  </p>  
  <p class="email">
    <input name="email" class="feedback-input" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                    <div id="email_error" class="val_error"></div>
  </p>  
  <p class="hpnum">
    <input name="hpnum" type="text" id="contactnum" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Contact Number"/>
                    <div id="contact_error" class="val_error"></div>     
 </p>  
  <p class="text">
    <textarea name="text" id="comment" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
                    <div id="comment_error" class="val_error"></div>
  </p>

  <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue"/>
    <div class="ease"></div>
  </div>

</form>
</div>
</div>
```

My Javascript:

```
    // GETTING ALL INPUT TEXT FIELDS
var username = document.forms["Form"]["name"];
var email = document.forms["Form"]["email"];
var comment = document.forms["Form"]["comment"];
var contact = document.forms["Form"]["hpnum"];
// GETTING ALL ERROR OBJECTS
var name_error = document.getElementById("name_error");
var email_error = document.getElementById("email_error");
var comment_error = document.getElementById("comment_error");   
var contact_error = document.getElementById("contact_error");
        name_error.textContent = "Username is required";
function validateForm(){

    // VALIDATE USERNAME
    if(username.value == ""){
        name_error.textContent = "Username is required";
        username.style.border = "1px solid red";
        username.focus();
        return false;
    }
    // VALIDATE EMAIL
    else if(email.value == ""){
        email_error.textContent = "Email is required";
        email.style.border = "1px solid red";
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(contact.value == ""){
        comment_error.textContent = "Comment is required";
        comment.style.border = "1px solid red";
        comment.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(comment.value == ""){
        comment_error.textContent = "Comment is required";
        comment.style.border = "1px solid red";
        comment.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else{
        alert("Thank You! For Your Feedback!");
    }
}
```

Comment: In this copepen, it seems to be working... Do you get any errors? What browser are you using? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzogLM

Comment: I am using chrome I also tried Firefox still not working

Comment: Interesting. Where is your feedbackscript.js file? Are you sure it is in the right place?

Comment: arh nvm i have fix it. I tried like Jimbot says putting the global variables into the functions ty all:)

Comment: Excellent! Well done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I see: your global variables are populated at load time, while your validateForm() functions is triggered later and the values have probably changed. But the variables content are not updated.